# Help on fractional programming

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, linearization

I need help transforming this Mathematical Programming model into a solvable model

$ \min \delta$

$\frac{190(E_j-\sum_ix_{ij})}{P_j-\sum_iQ_ix_{ij}}\leq\delta \ \ \ \ \forall j$

$\sum_j x_{ij} \leq S_i \ \ \ \ \forall i$

$ P_j-\sum_iQ_ix_{ij}\geq0.4P_j\ \ \ \ \forall j$

$ \sum_ix_{ij}\geq0\ \ \ \ \forall j$

$x_{ij}$ is a continuous variable, all the rest are parameters

I tried fractional programming transformation but I can't get it right. Thanks in advance. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are all symbols variables? Are there any bounds or domain restriction (e.g. integer vs continuous)? By solvable model, do you mean getting an analytical formula for the minimum?

Comment: As an aside, it's usually expected to type out the math directly in the post using MathJax. In addition to showing the effort you're putting in from your side, it makes it easier to write up an answer using the equations in the post.
https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: x_ij is the only variable (continuous)

Ok I will rewrite the problem using MathJax, I will learn it. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: I have rewritten it using MathJax. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

One approach to solve this problem is to perform a bisection search on $\delta$.  For each fixed $\delta$, you can clear the denominator on the corresponding constraint to linearize.  If the resulting LP problem is infeasible, change the lower bound of the search interval to $\delta$.  If the resulting LP problem is feasible, change the upper bound of the search interval to $\delta$.  Repeat until the difference in bounds is sufficiently small.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it